# java.lang.NullPointerException for static field in Android library project

Tags: android, android-library

First to explain how projects are setup:

- Android Library project with two classes:

  - UserActivity - uses static field in HolderClass
  - HolderClass - this one has static field Data
- Android Application that references Library project, has only one class:

  - StarterActivity - when app is started, in onCreate it sets static field Data to some value, and it starts UserActivity

Now, the problem is: *sometimes* I get java.lang.NullPointerException for that static field Data - as if I never initialized it (or value got deleted in meantime). It never happened on my test device, but I keep getting error reports from client devices. I can only guess how that happens - maybe user navigates away from app, then comes back and system recreates whole application context, but in that context HolderClass has empty static field Data?

My question:

Is initialization of that static field from Activity's onCreate wrong approach? Should I put data in ApplicationContext? Or do something else?

I am open for all suggestions.

P.S. If you have problem visualizing from description, here is how everything I've said would look in code:

```
// IN ANDROID APP PROJECT
public class StarterActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        // just start activity in library
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, AutolaunchActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(myIntent, 1);    
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // exit when activity from library exits
        finish();       
    }
}


// IN LIBRARY PROJECT

public class HolderClass {
    public static String Data;
}

public class UserActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 

        // init layout  
    }

    public void someButtonClicked() {
        HolderClass.Data.trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to show some code?

Comment: Post the error report to see what exactly you are getting.

Comment: I've extracted important lines and posted code example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this was basically the problem of global variables - in the end I've solved it by reading this answer: [How to declare global variables in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)

Answer (score 1):

The usual ways of sharing data between activities is documented [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/framework.html#3). The intermittent nature of the error suggests a timing problem to me. Are you using threads in some of your initialization? Also, do you know if the NPE happening in StarterActivity or UserActivity?

Comment: Nah, it's not threading problem... reading the link you've sent it point in that "application process is killed and then recreated direction", quote: "If the shared data needs to be retained across points where the application process can be killed, then place that data in persistent storage like Application Preferences, SQLite DB, Files or ContentProviders."